# Overriding RenderBody content without redirecting user in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, security

I was trying to do this:

```
<body>
    <div id="Page">
        <div id="TopBar">
            <div id="TopBarLogo">
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Weblogo.png")" />
            </div>
            <div>
                @{ Html.RenderAction("MenuPartial", "MenuPartial"); }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Content">
            @if (SessionWrapper.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                @RenderBody()
            }
            else
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("AccessDeniedPartial");
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But ofc this is not allowed, as I need to have @RenderBody() or an exception occurs.
The problem is that this solution would have been so neat, I still want to render the top part of the page, but I would like to override the content unless user is logged in.

The only other solution I can think of is to do the check in the controller and return another view. The problem with that is that I would have to repeat this code in every controller which makes me sad.

Is there any way to globally override the content similar to above, without redirecting the user to another url? If there is, could you please give me a nudge in the right direction. I seem to be a bit stuck in my current mindset.

Im not using the default Microsoft security classes (FormsAuthentication), nor am I able to in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `AccessDenied` view in the Views/Shared folder that has the same content as your `AccessDeniedPartial`.
Leave the `RenderBody` as it is:

```
<div class="Content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Create an `LogOnAuthorizeAttribute` that will check for authentication, otherwise show the AccessDenied view.

```
public class LogOnAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!SessionWrapper.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult {ViewName = "AccessDenied"};
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the `LogOnAuthorizeAttribute` to be added to each controller, add it as a filter to the `GlobalFilterCollection` in `Global.asax`.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new LogOnAuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The only other solution I can think of is to do the check in the controller and return another view.

yes do that

> The problem with that is that I would have to repeat this code in every controller which makes me sad.

well no, if you use the new aspect-oriented programming model of mvc, which is based on filter attributes. Check the AuthorizeAttribute and the filter model of asp.net mvc.

```
[Authorize]
public ViewResult MyAction(...)
```

You can customize the behavior of this Authorize attribute quite easily.

Also you can read more about aspect oriented programming here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming